# Finding the impulse response of $y[n]=\tfrac12y[n-1]-\tfrac15y[n-2]+x[n]$

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

I'm new to signals processing and up until now we'd assume that $x[n]$ is the input and $y[n]$ is the output, and when I wanted to get the impulse response I'd simply replace $x[n]$ with sigma and $y[n]$ with $h[n]$.
However, I want to find the DTFT of the impulse response of $$y[n]=\tfrac12y[n-1]-\tfrac15y[n-2]+x[n]$$ and it I think that would create a long chain of $h[n]$'s.
I thought of putting the equation as $y[n]=\tfrac12y[n-1]-\tfrac15y[n-2]+x[n]$. and assume that $y[n]$ is the input. Is this correct?
How do I know which is the input and output signal?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a long chain of $h[n]$'s.  Could you edit your question to clarify?  If you mean that $h[n]$ will never go to zero for $n > 0$ -- yes, that's true, your difference equation is for an infinite impulse response filter.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to solve it in the Z Transform domain:
$$
y(z)=\frac12y(z)z^{-1}-\frac15y(z)z^{-2}+x(z)
$$
And then solve for $y(z)/x(z)$, which is the very definition of Impulse Response in the Z Domain:
$$
y(z)-\frac12y(z)z^{-1}+\frac15y(z)z^{-2}=x(z)\\
h(z)={y(z) \over x(z)}=\frac1{1-\frac12z^{-1}+\frac15z^{-2}}
$$

From here, since you want the DTFT, you need to remember than the Z Space and the Time Discrete Space are related through the variable change, with $\omega=2\pi f=2\pi/dt$ and $dt$ the sampling time.
$$
z=e^{s}=e^{j\omega}
$$

Thus the requested Impulse Response in DTFT Domain is:
$$
h(\omega)=\frac1{1-\frac12e^{-j\omega}+\frac15e^{-2j\omega}}
$$

As you can see, you can simply start directy from time to DTFT Space by realizing that $y(t-t_0) \to y(\omega)e^{j\omega t0}$, which leads to the same expressions:
$$
y(\omega)=\frac12y(\omega)e^{-j\omega}-\frac15y(\omega)e^{-2j\omega}+x(\omega)\\
h(\omega)={y(\omega) \over x(\omega)}=\frac1{1-\frac12e^{-j\omega}+\frac15e^{-2j\omega}}
$$

I preferred the Z Space way, since the DTFT Space is seldom used, in place for the more common Z Space for Discrete Time applications.

Comment: You might have some notational convention issues here.  Usually one-domain space (normally *"time domain"* is lower case, and the transformed domain (*"frequency domain"* or *"Z domain"*) is upper case.